# The lower bound on the probability of error in quantum hypothesis testing

Tags: fidelity, state-discrimination

Prove the following lower bound on the probability of error $P_e$ in a quantum hypothesis test to distinguish $\rho$ from $\sigma$:
\begin{align}
    P_e \geq \frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{1-F(\rho, \sigma)}\right).
\end{align}
This is the exercies 9.3.1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1445.pdf.

Comment: look back to equation 9.50. That gives you the success probability, which is 1- error probability in terms of a norm between two states. Apply corollary 9.3.2 to replace that norm with $\epsilon$ and hence $F$.

Comment: Thank you DaftWullie.